# de linha adicione 2 espaços no final _

Tags: cobol

```
like so
```

adicione identificador de linguagem para habilitar código destacado

```py
def function(foo):
    print(foo)
```

coloque retornos entre os parágrafos
para quebra de linha adicione 2 espaços no final
*itálico* ou **negrito**
recue o código em 4 espaços
escapes de acentos graves `parecido _portanto_`
destaque colocando > no início da linha
para criar links (utilize https sempre que possível)
<https://example.co

Answer (score -2):

Boa Noite, Sou nova nesse site então se não ficar muito bem explicado me desculpa aí.
Bem, tentando te ajudar nisso aqui, pelo que eu entendi, vc quer centralizar essa caixa cinza na página de 80px esquerdo e para cima e 80px da direita para baixo.
Bom pra você fazer no CSS usamos uma propriedade chamada *Position*.Nela você usa diversas valores que pode atende-lo. Nesse caso creio que seja da seguinte forma.

#box{ position: fixed;} Nesse exemplo vc deixa fixo na tela
Dependendo do local que vc colocar vc usa dessa forma:
#box{ position-right: fixed;}(no caso fixo na parte direita)
#box{ position-left: fixed;}(no caso fixo na parte esquerda)
#box{ position-top: fixed;}(no caso fixo na parte de cima)
#box{ position-bottom: fixed;}(no caso fixo na parte de baixo)
((obs: Você pode usar mais de uma propriedade dessa))
Com o margin e o padding você pode ainda colocar um espaçamento interno e externo que fica em relação a algo que você colocou.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score -4):

pelo menos pra mim, ta bem confuso a pergunta.
mais de uma forma geral, position é assim:

```
< div position relative> 
 < div position absolute> sempre absoluto em relaçao ao pai
< /div position relative>
```

n tem erro.
pra posicionar, vc usa as propriedades de position, top, right etc

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: como eu disse, seu elemento vai ser absoluto ao pai. 
o pai relativo, o filho absoluto. se vc tornar o bloco preto absoluto relativo ao pai dele, voce pode tentar tornar aquele quadrado fixed. mais vejo indo pra um nivel de complexidade que vc tem meios para contornar.